# EntityFramework и Oracle. Несовпадение типов

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Привет. Я сейчас работаю работаю с базами данных Oracle. Хотел использовать на клиенте EntityFramework, но столкнулся с такой проблемой: при попытке достать данные с использованием модели данных, получаю ошибку "несовпадения типов". В таблице есть поле типа NUMBER, в модели это поле создается с типом Byte. B этом есть своя логика, но загвоздка в том, что в этом поле в БД хранятся также отрицательные значения, и при попытке присвоить отрицательное значение полю с типом Byte мне и выбивает ошибку. Пробовал в ручную изменить поле в модели данных на SByte или что-то вроде, все тщетно. Вылазит ошибка типа: "...oracle.number не совместим с edm.SByte...". Может кто что подскажет?

Comment: на int или long попробуйте заменить, с этими типами oracle работает без проблем, во всяком случае у меня. Тип NUMBER соответствует OracleDbType.Decimal и он, как ни странно, без шаманства приводится к long и int, но не к Sysytem.Decimal. Если поможет, дальше уже можно думать как привести к тому что вам нужно

Comment: @rdorn, пробовал - не выходит. Вообще интересно получается: если создавать модель на основе EF 5.x, то поле с типом NUMBER(2) приводится к short, а при использовании EF 6.x - уже к типу byte. А когда я пытаюсь работать с EF 5.x, вообще не могу инициализировать класс контекста.